# How to save changes in EF Core 3.1.3 in a many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm trying to save changes on a database using EF Core 3.1.3, .net core 3.1 with blazor pages.  The model contains multiple children, and each child has another child that may be the same entity.  This is a sample code:

```
    public class Currency
    {
        [Key]
        public int CurrencyID { get; set; }

        public string Country{ get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public string ISOCode{ get; set; }

        public bool Active{ get; set; }
    }

    public class PaymentDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int PaymentDetailID{ get; set; }

        public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

        public decimal Amount{ get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CurrencyID")]
        public int CurrencyID{ get; set; }
        public Moneda Currency{ get; set; }

    }

    public class Payment
    {
        [Key]
        public int PaymentID{ get; set; }

        public string ReferenceNumber{ get; set; }

        public ICollection<PaymentDetail> PaymentDetail{ get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CurrencyID")]
        public int CurrencyID{ get; set; }
        public Currency Currency{ get; set; }

        public decimal TotalAmount{ get; set; }

    }
```

As you can see, I have multiple children that will use the same currency and the parent may also use the same currency, so when I try to save the changes I get an error that there is an entity with the same currencyID already being tracked.

I know one solution is to nullify all navigation properties before trying to save changes, that works for saving data into the database but that breaks my blazor page since I'm displaying some of the properties to the user.

I have tried using State.Unchanged instead of nullify the navigation property but when I iterate through all the children and there is a second child that uses the same currency then I have the error that the entity is already being tracked.

I have also used .AsNoTracking() in my queries to get the currency, but it is also being tracked, i guess it happens when I use dbcontext.Add(Payment).

Is there another solution? Perhaps a way to check if the entity is already in unchanged state so I can skip it during iteration?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new instance of Payment and I copied only the information I wanted to save to the new instance.  This way I separated the View from the Model.